# IBM DB2 replication on secondary passive machine

Tags: db2

I have two machines. Both have their own disks. One machine runs active DB2 and the secondary machine has DB2 installed but not running (only one license). In case the DB goes down, I need to start the secondary DB2 instance. Databases should come back online, it is not so critical that all latest data has been transferred. The

What is the easiest way to do this? One is to shutdown all databases every night and script a backup routine. Another is HADR, but in this case I'm not sure if HADR requires a spearate license, and if the DB2 instance on the secondary machine must be running (not possible because we only have one license)

Comment: This post is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow because it is not a problem about writing program code. This is a database administration question, and belongs on [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer each archived log each time the file is passed to the archive directory in the primary database.

You transfer that file to the log directory in the second machine.

From time to time, you can perform a "roll forward to end of logs", and that will reduce the time in case of a role switch.

You can also backup the primary and transfer that backup to the other machine. But you have to restore it when switching, and this could be very long.

Probably, you can also install Express-C in the second one (Two DB2s installed), and you roll forward or restore periodically with this edition. In case of switch, you just change the db2 instance or create a symbolic link to the binaries in order to activate the db2 features not included in express-c.

Comment: I hope you are using *NIX, because in Windows is a little harder to do that, but possible.

Comment: Actually it's quite easy to do this on Windows if both machines are in a domain because you can use UNC paths in the `BACKUP DATABASE` command and in `LOGARCHMETH1` to take care of getting the files to the secondary server immediately.